# Multiple values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, Table A & Table B

Table A:

```
G.R.N   ITEM      QUANTITY
--------------------------
  1     ABC001      150
  1     CBD001      150
  1     SDB001      100
```

Table B:

```
DELIVERY    ITEM    QUANTITY
-------------------------------
34          ABC001  50
35          ABC001  40
36          ABC001  60
37          CBD001  50
38          CBD001  40
39          CBD001  10
```

Is it possible to get desired output like this:

```
G.R.N   ITEM    QUANTITY  DELIVERY  ITEM    QUANTITY DIFFERENCE
1   ABC001  150   34,35,36  ABC001   150        0
1   CBD001  150   37,38,39  CBD001   100        50
1   SDB001  100              100
```

Answer (score 3):

for recent version of sql-server  (sql-server  2017)

You could try using left join, sum and group by

```
select A.GRN
    , A.ITEM
    , A.QUANTITY
    , STRING_AGG(B.DELIVERY,',' ) DELIVERY
    , B.ITEM 
    , SUM(B.QUANTITY )
    , A.QUANTITY - SUM(B.QUANTITY )  QUANTITY_DIFFERENCE 
from tableA A 
left JOIN tableB B ON A.ITEM = B.ITEM 
group by  A.ITEM
```

Comment: Shouldn't the subtraction be reversed?

Comment: Maybe `A.QUANTITY - SUM(B.QUANTITY)` instead of `SUM(B.QUANTITY)  - A.QUANTITY`?

Comment: "Recent" is an ambiguous term.  For example, I recently dusted the living room.  My wife will vigorously deny that.  :)  +1

Comment: I am getting an error ''STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.' when I do this coding in SQl server

Comment: @JohnCappelletti  .. Probably  .. your wife have some elements for this  .. answer updated .. for a more specific "recent" ..

Comment: string_agg start from  sql.server 2017  ..  if you have not  .. you could try using a more complex way  .. here a sample  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/56195835-748a-4fb9-8302-391b1dbc4e43/substitute-for-stringagg-in-sql-2016?forum=transactsql

Comment: @DeePak  . have you see the content of the link  ?  which db version are you using?  .if you have not sql-server 2017  .. you should use The for xml approach

Comment: I am using SQL server 2016

Answer (score 2):

You can join the tables using the `item` column. If you perform a `left join`, then items from the first table will be returned even if there is no matching `item` value in the second table.

The [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) aggregation function concatenates the values in the group together using the second argument as the delimiter - in this case a comma.

```
select
    A.[G.R.N],
    A.ITEM,
    A.QUANTITY,
    STRING_AGG(B.DELIVERY, ',') as DELIVERY,
    SUM(B.QUANTITY) as DELIVERY_QUANTITY,
    A.QUANTITY - SUM(B.QUANTITY) as QUANTITY_DIFFERENCE
from A
left join B on A.ITEM = B.ITEM
group by A.ITEM
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a string aggregation   34,35,36